# A file called javaw keeps attempting to randomly open in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I get the open file dialog in Windows 10 that asks me which app I want to use to open a file called javaw. This happens randomly every day.

If I choose to allow it to open in Notepad a blank page opens with the title javaw.txt with nothing inside of it. I just close Notepad and nothing else happens.

How can I figure out what is making this repeatedly happen? I have Windows Defender active and it says the system is clean. I've downloaded MalWareBytes and it shows no malware.

I'm thinking it's some kind of glitch but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably installed a product that was written in Java.
Do you have Java installed? As it does not seem to be available.

If the problem arrives only after boot, then the product is set to start with Windows
(or with logon). You may verify it by booting once in Safe mode, where it
shouldn't happen.

If the problem arrives from time to time, not necessarily immediately after boot,
then the product is set to run as a scheduled task.

You can use the free
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to search for startup items of the above type.
You can use Autoruns to undo a startup item by clicking the check-mark
of likely candidates, verifying by a reboot, then undoing if wrong by resetting
the check-mark.
Continue until you find the product.

Comment: Thank you.  I found the culprit with your advice.  I ran Autoruns and found the javaw.exe.  It's from a program called WeblocOpener and I think it's attempting to update but is having trouble.  I'll take it from here.  You just saved me a lot of avagration and I've now learned a powerful new tool.

Answer (score 0):

javaw(.exe) is part of Java.  Go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, scroll down for Java and uninstall it.

Also let Windows Defender run a full scan and see if there are any viruses.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I followed the advice of harrymc and used Autoruns to find what was creating the issue.  Through Autoruns I searched for javaw.exe. It's coming from a program called WeblocOpener and I think it's attempting to update but is having trouble doing so.  I've since manually updated WeblocOpener and the issue is resolved.